# How to set predefined number of cycles in python?

Tags: python, list, indexing, cycle

i have an equation to plot the state of charge of a battery SOC[t,c] based on hourly(time index t in time_set from 1 to 24) power values. The power is for each charging station (index c from 1 to 4) and for each charging station, i have limited number of batteries to be charged (index i from 1 to 6). The cycle in my case is when the i battery finish charging and the state of charge reach 0.8 A part of my code is as follow but in the results, i got more than 6 cycles (i). Anyone has an idea how to limit the number of batteries to be charged to 6 and got 6 cycles from pyhton.

```
for t in time_set:
    for c in range(1,5):
        i=0
        Pev[t,c]<=50
        Pev[t,c]>=-50
        SOC[t,c]<=0.95
        SOC[t,c]>=0.2
        SOC[t,c]==SOC[t-1,c,i]+(delta*Pev[t,c,i]/40)
        if SOC[t,c]>=0.8
           i+=1
```

Answer (score -1):

This code as a standalone is not working. Could u post the whole code? And I assume, you use i just to count the number of circles, but only when SOC[t,c]>=0.8?

Do you mean more than 6 circles in total? Of coure, bc. you have an outer loop, too. ("for t in time_set:")

Comment: yes i want to count number of circles for SOC[t,c]>=0.8 and this number mus not exceed 6 circles. As my code is so long and i have excel input i cannot post it. Do you have some ideas, i can try in my code and tell you.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can help you: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_for_nested.asp

Answer (score -1):

enter code hereIf you want to exit both loops when you iterated 6 times through the inner loop, u can use "break"

```
exit_t_loop = False
loop_number = 0
for t in time_set:
    if exit_t_loop:
        break
    for c in range(1, 5):
        i = 0
        Pev[t, c] <= 50
        Pev[t, c] >= -50
        SOC[t, c] <= 0.95
        SOC[t, c] >= 0.2
        SOC[t, c] == SOC[t - 1, c, i] + (delta * Pev[t, c, i] / 40)
        if SOC[t, c] >= 0.8:
            i += 1
        loop_number += 1
        print(f'loop number: {loop_number}')
        if loop_number == 6:
            exit_t_loop = True
```

Comment: i edited can u try again? is it this loop u want 6 times?

Comment: with this new code i got only one cycle and not 6. the previous code i got infinity number of cycles. i think the code is improved but still not getting the 6 cycles.